# Javascript - generating random pairs of numbers if pair doesn't already exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, search

Edit: If you read Matt Bryant's answer, you'll see that it should work but he uses indexOf() method and that method doesn't work with I.E 8 or later and I need it to work on I.E 8. I tried doing this as a work around to the indexOf() method but it's not working.

```
var tester = -1;
for (var test=0; test<xposition.length; test++) {
    if (x == xposition[0]) {
        tseter = x;
    }
}
```

Any idea why it doesn't work?

Original question: 
So I want to generate random pairs of numbers but only if the pairs of number didn't already be generated. Here is what I tried, hopefully if you read what I tried, you will understand what it is exactly which I need.

```
function randomPairs() {
    var xposition = []; //array which holds all x coordinates
    var yposition = []; //array which holds all y coordinates
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) { //do everything below 5 times (generate 5 pairs)

        var x = getRandom(1,7); //generate new x point
        var y = getRandom(2,7); //generate new y point

        if ( jQuery.inArray(x, xposition) ) { //if newly generated x point is already in the xposition array (if it was already previously generated
             var location = xposition.indexOf(x) //find the index of the existing x

             if (y == yposition[location]) { //if the newly generated y points equals the same y point in the same location as x, except in the yposition array

                 while ( y == yposition[location]) {
                     y = getRandom(2, 7); //change y
                 }
             }
       }
  }
  xposition.push(x); //put x into the array
  yposition.push(y); //put y into the array
}
```

So, any idea why it isn't working? Am I using the jQuery.inArray() and the .indexOf() method properly?

Oh, and getRandom is

```
function getRandom(min, max) {
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
}
```

basically, it generates a number between the min and max.

Also, when I tried to do

```
alert(xposition);
alert(yposition);
```

it is blank.

Comment: Can you show us what your `getRandom()` function does? why are the params for x and y different? Do you just pass in the scale of the axis and do a `Math.random`? Just making sure.

Comment: `function randomPairs() { return [4,4]; }`.  Directly inspired from http://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: `jQuery.inArray(x, xposition)` return the index of the element if is exist so why are you search inside this function index of?

Comment: @aug whoops I just edited my post and showed what getRandom() does.

Comment: `x` and `y` are declared inside the scope of for loop and you push it in `xposition` and `yposition` outside it

Comment: @RakeshJuyal I dont get it. what does the xkcd.com/221 mean and how does it relate to this thread?

Comment: its a joke dude ... ironic enough that it needs to be explained ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that you are adding `x` and `y` to the array outside of the loop.  A fix for this (plus a removal of the unneeded jQuery) is:

```
function randomPairs() {
    var xposition = []; //array which holds all x coordinates
    var yposition = []; //array which holds all y coordinates
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) { //do everything below 5 times (generate 5 pairs)

        var x = getRandom(1,7); //generate new x point
        var y = getRandom(2,7); //generate new y point

        var location = xposition.indexOf(x);
        if (location > -1) { //if newly generated x point is already in the xposition array (if it was    already previously generated
            if (y == yposition[location]) { //if the newly generated y points equals the same y point in  the same location as x, except in the yposition array
                while ( y == yposition[location]) {
                    y = getRandom(2, 7); //change y
                }
            }
        }
        xposition.push(x); //put x into the array
        yposition.push(y); //put y into the array
    }
}
```

Note that you should probably return something from this function.

If you have to support old browsers, replace the line

```
var location = xposition.indexOf(x);
```

with

```
var location = jQuery.inArray(x, xposition);
```

Comment: uhm what does the 'if (location > -1) do? does xposition.indexOf(x) return a negative number if x is not found in the array?

Comment: If `x` is not in the array, `indexOf(x)` returns `-1`.  Otherwise it returns an index, which must be greater than or equal to 0.

Comment: hm, did you try the code you provided on your computer? Did it work for you?

Comment: for some reason for me, the code stops working when it reaches "var location = xposition.indexOf(x);"

Comment: it says that object doesn't support this property or method because it does work in IE 8 and earlier apparently. Any way to work around this? And yea, I gotta make it work for IE8 -.-

Comment: The fix for that would be to use the jQuery method.  I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

One of the main issue with this approach is that you have to think of cases when there are multiple unique pairs with the same x or y value.

`x = [1, 1, 1], y = [1, 2, 3]`

Note that Array.indexOf only returns the **first** index when the given element can be found in the array. So you would have to recursively run it beginning from the index you found the match from.

A simple approach of generating a unique pair of integers can be done without jquery:
http://jsfiddle.net/WaFqv/

I'm assuming the order does matter, so the `x = 4, y = 3 & x = 3, y = 4` would be considered as two unique pairs.